# Table td alignment issue?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make the button align up with the textbox, but I can not get it to work, if you need more code, I will be glad to post it :)

[image]

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/FFcAu/

```
<table class="chatMain" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">

    <tr>

        <td align="center" class="MainView" valign="middle">1</td>

        <td align="center" valign="middle" class="SideAd" width="185px" rowspan="3">AD</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td align="center" class="controls" valign="middle">

            <textarea class="chatInput"></textarea>

            <button type="submit">Send</button>

        </td>                                   

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Seeming as you posted with the CSS tag and you're using classes, you must be using some CSS somewhere. At the very least we'll need to see your CSS. Preferably a link so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: sorry, look at the jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `vertical-align: middle` to form elements themselves.

Entire contents (as a solid thing) of table cell are vertically aligned within the cell while mutual aligning of each inline element inside contents is specified via `vertical-align` of these inline elements, not table cell.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` and `float: left` to your `.chatInput` and `button` class:

```
.chatInput
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height: 75px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    outline: none;
    resize:none;
}

button {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:75px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/xH8sm/